# Unable to load csv file into Snowflake

Tags: csv, loading, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Iam getting the below error when I try to load CSV From my system to Snowflake table:

Unable to copy files into table.
Numeric value '"4' is not recognized File '@EMPP/ui1591621834308/snow.csv', line 2, character 25 Row 1, column "EMPP"["SALARY":5] If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be loading your CSV with the file format option of `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'` specified.

This option will allow reading any fields properly quoted with the `"` character, and even support such fields carrying the delimiter character as well as the `"` character if properly escaped. Some examples that could be considered valid:

```
CSV FORM   | ACTUAL DATA
------------------------
abc        | abc
"abc"      | abc
"a,bc"     | a,bc
"a,""bc""" | a,"bc"
```

In particular, notice that the **final** example [follows the specified rule](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-csv):

> When a field contains this character, escape it using the same character. For example, if the value is the double quote character and a field contains the string A "B" C, escape the double quotes as follows:
>
> `A ""B"" C`

If your CSV file carries quote marks within the data but is not necessarily quoting the fields (and delimiters and newlines do not appear within data fields), ***you can remove the `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY` option*** from your file format definition and just read the file at the delimited (`,`) fields.

If your CSV does use quoting, ensure that whatever is producing the CSV files is using a valid CSV format writer and not simple string munging, and recreate it with the quotes properly escaped. If the above data example is to be considered valid in quoted form, it must instead appear within the file as `"4"` or `4`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you have a value in your file that contains a `"4` which is being added into a table that has a number field for that value.  Since that isn't a number, it fails.  This appears to be happening in your very first row of your file, so you could open it up and take a look at the value.  If its just one record, you can add the `ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE'` to your command, so that it skips it and moves on.